# Is in my php code line something insecure?

Tags: php, wordpress

In one of my child theme template pages I wanted to implement the following line:

```
<div id="fullsize-preview" style="background-image: url(http://www.myurlcom/image-folder/<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>.jpg)"></div>
```

I need this to have responsive images differing in measure and size depending on browser width for each post.

I was very happy with this solution but now I read in some places that it could be something highly insecure to do. Something that is called SQL injection.

There is also a webpage often referred to in this regard called “Bobby Tables”. I tried to read it but quite honestly I do understand not a word of what is displayed there. Not one. I am sorry.

So my simple question is: is my code dangerous or is it NOT the case here?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: For your information SQL injection works when you interact database based on input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A serious `NO`. As you do not have to take the output as input and the output (`$post`) is already processed by wordpress. And SQL injection works when you have to query with database building on your query. Wordpress Uses PDO and Query processing to keep you safe.